# Amazon Lex AlphaNumeric slot issue

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-lex, aws-chatbot

[Answer for slot by Amazon Lex doesn't when user input are more than 2 words.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zte0Q.png)

I am having troubles with Amazon Lex and Lambda when the user input would not go through when there is more than 2 words when used the "AMAZON.AlphaNumeric" slot type. Does anyone know how to counter this issue?

I hope to see the user input accepting more words and also detecting the words input by the custom slot types on Amazon Lex.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Lex doesn't really have a built in way to capture free-form text in the way you've described.

The `AlphaNumeric` slot type isn't meant to capture more than a couple of words which is why it's not working for your purpose. [It is primarily suggested for capturing things such as vehicle identification numbers, ID numbers, or certain postal codes. It also supports regular expressions to restrict these further.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/built-in-slot-alphanumeric.html)

If you want to configure your Lex to accept more free-form text like you've shown in your screenshot, you'll need to create a Lambda function to access the `inputTranscript`.

It's recommended that you create a custom slot type and train it with data that is similar to what you expect from the user. I have *sometimes* had it work with the `AlphaNumeric` slot type but this unreliable in some cases. As you've already experienced, Lex slots tend to leave out words and phrases which is why you'll need to create a Lambda to access the `inputTranscript`. The `inputTranscript` is the last text received from the user in its entirety.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62058978/what-is-amazon-lex-inbuilt-slot-type-for-description-or-notes/62079381#62079381) goes into more detail on how to accomplish this. I think it will help you. Good luck and let me know if you have more questions.